# Best way to connect node.js and sphinx

Tags: mysql, node.js, sphinx

I'm trying to search in sphinx from node.js code. The only way to do it I know is to connect to searchd as to mysqld server. I'd absolutely all known mysql libraries, but no of them even connected to sphinx.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try to use https://github.com/kurokikaze/limestone, but it may be a bit outdated.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way can be: Install Sphinx table engine to MySQL and use it using any Node.js-MySQL connector.

The better solution will be to implement sphinx client in node.js - it should be pretty easy.
Just check the Sphinx PHP API - it's not so hard to recode it with node.js sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to the right port? To query the latest version of Sphinx with a MySQL client you need to configure a MySQL protocol listener like so:

`listen = localhost:9306:mysql41`

...and then connect to that port (9306 in this case) with your client.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install sphinxapi
npm install mysql
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      localAddress      : '127.0.0.1',
      port      : '9306'
    }
);
 
connection.connect();
 
var queryString = "SELECT date FROM emails WHERE MATCH('@message mysql')limit 100";
 
connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
 
    for (var i in rows) {
        console.log('date:', rows[i].date);
    }
});
 
connection.end();
```